# How can I put a matrix in a figure caption?

Tags: math-mode, captions, amsmath, matrices

I would like to put a matrix in a figure caption. The following example demonstrates the idea:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphics,  epsfig, psfrag}  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(-72,-75)
\put(12,-68){\small$\alpha_2$}
\put(-15,-71){\small$\alpha_1$}
\put(-50,-60){\small$-\alpha_1$}
\put(-47,-44){\small$2\alpha_1+\alpha_2$}
\put(-60,-10){\small$-2\alpha_1-\alpha_2$}
\end{picture}
\caption{Some roots, associated to the Cartan matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile this produces

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }
```

I assume this means I shouldn't use the `\}` character in captions. But how can I make a matrix without one?

The actual figure is much more complicated and invokes the named packages as well as the `picture` environment, which is why I included them; the image here has no mathematical meaning.

Comment: Just a quick hint: You'll make your small matrix much more readable, and your code easier to read/debug in the process, if you define the matrix as a macro of the form, say, `\newcommand\cartanmatrix{\ensuremath{\textstyle\big({\begin{smallmatrix}\phantom{-}2& -2 \\-1&\phantom{-}2\end{smallmatrix}}\big)}}` and then refer to it later as `\cartanmatrix`. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boxing the `smallmatrix` first also solves the problem. For this, you have to define a box using `\newsavebox{<box>}` and store the contents using `\savebox{<box>}{<stuff>}`:

```
\newsavebox{\smlmat}% Box to store smallmatrix content
\savebox{\smlmat}{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}
```

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\smlmat}% Box to store smallmatrix content
\savebox{\smlmat}{$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$}

\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(-72,-75)
\put(12,-68){\small$\alpha_2$}
\put(-15,-71){\small$\alpha_1$}
\put(-50,-60){\small$-\alpha_1$}
\put(-47,-44){\small$2\alpha_1+\alpha_2$}
\put(-60,-10){\small$-2\alpha_1-\alpha_2$}
\end{picture}
\caption{Some roots, associated to the Cartan matrix~\usebox{\smlmat}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: This will fail if a List of Figures needs to be produced.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You are correct.

Comment: Moving the lines `\newsavebox{...}`, `\savebox{...}` to the preamble solves the problem with `\listoffigures`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the optional argument of `\caption`:

```
\caption[Roots associated to the Cartan matrix]{Some roots, associated to the Cartan matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.}
```

After all, the matrix wouldn't look good in a list of figures.

Another way of avoiding the error is to load the `caption` package an using the `singlelinechek=off` option; this approach, however, will fail if a List of Figures needs to be produced:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphics,  epsfig, psfrag}  
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{picture}(0,0)(-72,-75)
\put(12,-68){\small$\alpha_2$}
\put(-15,-71){\small$\alpha_1$}
\put(-50,-60){\small$-\alpha_1$}
\put(-47,-44){\small$2\alpha_1+\alpha_2$}
\put(-60,-10){\small$-2\alpha_1-\alpha_2$}
\end{picture}
\caption{Some roots, associated to the Cartan matrix $\left(\protect\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2\protect\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why I should have expected that to work?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: The explanation is somehow involved, but you can read the first lines of Appendix **A.4 Errors** of the documentation of the `caption` package, and the links therein provided.