# Matrix in Section Heading

Tags: sectioning

Is it possible to place a matrix in a Section Heading?

This is my current attempt:

```
\section{Analyze the invertible $M= \left[ \begin{array}{rr}2 & 6 \\
2 & 4 \end{array} \right]$ matrix by doing the following:}
```

I want it to read:
[image]

Any help is appreciated as I am new.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}

Comment: I believe, this is a mathematical problem which should rather been typeset with `answers` or a similar package. It's possible, but the entry to the ToC must be protected

Comment: Use the `smallmatrix` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) instead of an `array` environment.

Comment: Related: [How can I put a matrix in a figure caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34374/5764)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `lrbox` to create a box containing the math stuff and then use it in the argument of `\section`.

First of all, add

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
```

in the preamble. Then embed the math stuff in the `lrbox`

```
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
$M= \left[ \begin{array}{rr}2 & 6 \\
2 & 4 \end{array} \right]$
\end{lrbox}
```

and finally print the box inside the `\section`:

```
\section{Analyze the invertible \usebox{\mybox} matrix by doing the following:}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
$M= \left[ \begin{array}{rr}2 & 6 \\
2 & 4 \end{array} \right]$
\end{lrbox}

\section{Analyze the invertible \usebox{\mybox} matrix by doing the following:}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn't disturb the `\tableofcontents` but consider using the optional argument of `\section` to print something different in the ToC, if you are printing it.

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of `\protect`s for the `toc` ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Protection for the math stuff written to toc
\section[{$M= \protect\left[\protect\begin{array}{rr}   2 & 6 \\   2 & 4 \protect\end{array}\protect\right]$}]{Analyze the invertible  matrix \protect{$M= \left[ \begin{array}{rr}
  2 & 6 \\
  2 & 4 
\end{array} \right]$}
 by doing the following:}

% protection for both heading and toc
\section{Analyse the matrix {$M= \protect\left[\protect\begin{array}{rr}   2 & 6 \\   2 & 4 \protect\end{array}\protect\right]$}
 by doing the following:}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An addition, using the environment "smallmatrix" may look better in a section title.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
$M=\small[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\small]$
\end{lrbox}
\tableofcontents
\section{Analyze the invertible {\usebox{\mybox}} by doing the following}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I have slightly improved your code by adding extra braces, otherwise the output is incorrect in a table of contents.

Comment: An alternative to the extra braces would have been a `\protect`